# Can't remove the trailing plus sign in an amount decomposition

Tags: c++, formatting

I have a simple program in which you input a value in a (Bulgarian) currency and it shows you the amount split in banknotes in the most economically way. For example for an amount of `91`, it should print `1*50 + 2*20 + 1`

Well, the problem is that when you input a small amount like 20 for example in the output there is a trailing "+" at the end (e.g. `1*20 +` instead of `1*20`). I would like to know how to not output the number if it's alone. `Levove` is the Bulgarian currency unit.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int Amount;
    cout << "Enter the amount of levove: ";
    cin >> Amount;
    unsigned int Fifty = 50;
    unsigned int Twenty = 20;
    unsigned int Ten = 10;
    unsigned int Five = 5;
    unsigned int Two = 2;
    unsigned int One = 1;
    unsigned int Levove = Amount;

    cout << Suma << " = ";

    if (Levove / Fifty == 0)
    {
    }
    else 
        if (Levove / Fifty == 1)
    {
        cout << Levove / Fifty << "*" << Fifty << "+";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << Levove / Fifty << "*" << Fifty << "+";
    }
        Levove %= Fifty;

    if (Levove / Twenty == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (Levove / Twenty == 1)
    {
        cout << Levove / Twenty << "*" << Twenty << "+";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << Levove / Twenty << "*" << Twenty << "+";
    }
        Levove %= Twenty;


    if (Levove / Ten == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (Levove / Ten == 1)
    {
        cout << Levove / Ten << "*" << Ten << "+";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << Levove / Ten << "*" << Ten << "+";
    }
        Levove %= Ten;


    if (Levove / Five == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (Levove / Five == 1)
    {
        cout << Levove / Five << "*" << Five << "+";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << Levove / Five << "*" << Five << "+";
    }
        Levove %= Five;

    if (Levove / Two == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (Levove / Two == 1)
    {
        cout << Levove / Two << "*" << Two << "+";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << Levove / Two << "*" << Two << "+";
    }
        Levove %= Two;


    if (Levove / One == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (Levove / One == 1)
    {
        cout << Levove / One << "*" << One;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << Levove / One << "*" << One;
    }
        Levove %= One;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "there is a plus in one of the side". Well, you wrote `<< "+";`. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

The problem is that you always output a "+" at the end of any coin (except the last one) without knowing if something will follow or not.

For example, with an amount of 20, the following condition would get triggered:

```
...
else if (Levove / Twenty == 1)
{
    cout << Levove / Twenty << "*" << Twenty << "+";
}
...
```

But at there is no remainder, nothing else will be printed, leaving you an ending trailer.

**How to solve it ?**

Everywhere you currently write a trailing "+",  you should change your code and make this happen only if there'd be a remainer:

```
... 
if (Levove / Twenty != 0)   // also think of simplifying the ifs
{
    cout << Levove / Twenty << "*" << Twenty ;
    Levove %= Twenty;  // this is only needed if Lenove/Twenty is not null. 
    if (Levove != 0) 
         cout <<" + ";
}
```

By the way, you could also simplify your `if .. else if .. else` constructs

**Additional remarks**

Looking at your code, I guess you are learning.  If you have already learned how to do a function, I would highly recommend you putting the repetitive part in a function:

```
unsigned int amount_to_coins (unsigned int amount, unsigned int coin_value) {
    unsigned int coins=amount / coin_value;  
    if (coins) 
    {
        cout << coins << "*" << coin_value ;
        amount %= coin_value;  
        if (amount) 
             cout <<" + ";
    }
    return amount; 
}
```

Your `main()` function would then become easier to read:

```
Levove = amount_to_coins (Levove, Fifty); 
Levove = amount_to_coins (Levove, Twenty); 
...
Levove = amount_to_coins (Levove, One); 
cout <<endl; 

if (Levove !=0)
    cout << "Now there must be a bug somewhere !"<<endl;
```